# Entity Framework System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am doing this:

```
User user = _usersRepository.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == "gigi", new string[] { "Roles" });
UnitOfWork.Current.Dispose();
```

and i don't get the roles associated to that user, i get that System.ObjectDisposedException.

If instead of doing that repository call , i simply do:

```
            User user;
            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities ())
            {
                user = ctx.Users.Include("Roles").SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == "gigi");
            }
```

i do get the roles.
What am i missing?

LE:This is how my base repository looks like:

```
    public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private DbContext _context;
        private IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

        protected DbContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (_context == null)
                {
                    EFUnitOfWork currentUnitOfWork = (EFUnitOfWork)UnitOfWork.Current;
                    _context = currentUnitOfWork.Context;
                }

                return _context;
            }
        }

        protected IDbSet<T> DbSet
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dbSet == null)
                {
                    _dbSet = Context.Set<T>();
                }

                return _dbSet;
            }
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Attach(T entity)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            Context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string[] includes=null)
        {            
            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (string property in includes)
                {
                    DbSet.Include(property);
                }
            }
            return DbSet.SingleOrDefault(where);
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string[] includes=null)
        {
            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (string property in includes)
                {
                    DbSet.Include(property);
                }
            }
            return DbSet.Where(where);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DbSet.Include()` returns a new `DbSet<T>` that includes that navigation property.
Since you don't use the returned DbSet, your `Include()` calls have no effect.

You need to assign the result of `Include()` to a local variable and use that instead of `DbSet`.